# hide pop up box with controllers help if user enter correct email id and password

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, login, popup, third-party-module

in pop up box, we are displaying login form. once user enter wrong email id or password, we are displaying message : `Invalid login/pw` , but once they enter correct details and click on login button, than user will be logged in.

but issue is pop up box will remain until we close the pop up manually with help of `close button` as in below image, but i want to hide the pop up box if login is `successfull`.

we are calling below function once login button clicked.

controllers

```
protected function _createProduct() 
 { 

   try { 
         if(isset($login) && (is_array($login) && !empty($login)) || ($login!="")){ 
         $session->login($login['username'], $login['password']); 
         $result['redirect'] = $this->_getRefererUrl() ? $this->_getRefererUrl() : Mage::getUrl('customer/account', array( 
         '_secure' => true 
          )); 
                $result['success']  = true; 

                $customerId         = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId(); 
         } 
         else{ 
          $customerId = ""; 
         } 

         if ($doSave) 
           $product->save();                             

        return $product;                   

         } 
       catch () {  }                                   
}
```

[image]

> update

i called the javascript file once user credentials are correct as : `Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addJs('js/hide/here.js');`

& in **here.js** file , i add the code to hide complete pop up using class as :

```
jQuery(".ajaxlogin-window").hide();
```

> html

```
<div class="ajaxlogin-window" id="something">
<form>
// email id and password code
<button>Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: after login just refresh the current  page & welcome back

Comment: i checked your idea and discussed with client, but for some reason we dont want to refresh....

Comment: you use ajax ? and which popup you are using ? is it fancybox ?

Comment: @MineshPatel yes we are using ajax and custom pop up....

Comment: `jQuery(".ajaxlogin-window").hide()` put this when you get success from ajax. it should work

Comment: @MineshPatel i added your code when i got success message , but after click on login, it showing `ajax refresh symbol` instead of hiding pop up : https://i.stack.imgur.com/jk0Z2.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call a javascript after the customer' credentials are correct.

Use this code to add a java script from your controller.

`Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addJs('js/path/here.js');`

> Update

You need to check function whether the customer is successful logged in or not, if you are getting the logged in customer than trigger the function to Hide the popup. But if customer is not logged in keep the popup as it is by showing the message of invalid username/password

Comment: means is i need to write the code in `here.js` to hide pop up box

Comment: Yes add your js code here to hide the popup .

Comment: i aded your code : `Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addJs('js/hide/here.js');` after line `$result['success'] = true;`  here.js : `function hideWindow() 
{ 

document.getElementById('something').style.display = 'none'; 

document.getElementById('ajaxlogin-mask').style.display = 'none';

 }` please correct me if i am wrong....

Comment: when i attached this code to `login` button, its hiding the pop up once we click on `login button = > `onclick hideWindow()`

Comment: I have updated my answer please check that.

Comment: okay, according to your updated answer , than javascript code  i am using is wrong , please be here , i will come back with updated code.....

Comment: also i tried this in here.js, but no luck : `function hideWindow() 
{ 
var isLoggedin = jQuery('#loggedin').val();

   if (isLoggedin) 
      {
    jQuery(".ajaxlogin-window").hide();
      }
  
   
}`